# Cannot convert this pointer

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have a class `Foo` which looks like this

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void set_bar(int val)
    {
        _bar = val;
    }

protected:
    int _bar;
};
```

which is inherited by class `Baz` which is declared as follows:

```
class Baz
    : public Foo
{
public:
    void set_baz(int val)
    {
        _baz = val;
    }

protected:
    int _baz;
};
```

and then i have a `Factory` class which contains a member variable of type `Baz`.

```
class Factory
{
protected:
    Baz _baz;
public:
    const Baz& get_baz() const 
    {
        return _baz;
    }
};
```

If I used `Factory` like this:

```
Factory f;
f.get_baz().set_bar(1);
```

It throws this `error C2662: 'Foo::set_bar' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Baz' to 'Foo &'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a non-const version of Factory::get_baz that returns a non-const reference to Baz:

```
class Factory
{
protected:
    Baz _baz;
public:
    const Baz& get_baz() const 
    {
        return _baz;
    }

    Baz& get_baz()
    {
        return _baz;
    }
};
```

When using a const Factory, the const version of get_baz will get invoked, otherwise the non-const version of get_baz will get invoked.

You should also refrain from using leading underscores in your names. See [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: I don't prefix my code with underscores in real code, thanks for the read though.

Answer (score 1):

The object returned by `get_baz` is constant, you cannot modify its contents.

Comment: Ouch, I didn't see that.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After calling get_baz you are getting **constant object and constant object can call only constant function.**

Answer (score 0):

You can only change the value if you return a non-const reference to your object.

If you return a non-const reference, why not just make the member public? You'll get the same effect...